# using a variable from a json.load in another function

Tags: python, json, variables

I am using an API for receiving TTN data from a device. i have created a function "def on_message(mqttc, obj, msg):", using a json.loads(msg.payload.decode('utf-8')) to receive mqtt data.
I want to pick the variable "node_data" and use in def devdata(). but it seems that i do not get anything but None.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import pybase64
import binascii


APPEUI = "0018B24441524632"
APPID = "adeunis_fieldtester"
PSW = "ttn-account-v2.vuQczD1bmPoghhaKjlIHR-iHovHIbYMpfWSKosPAGaU"

# Call back functions

# gives connection message
def on_connect(mqttc, mosq, obj, rc):
    print("Connected with result code:" + str(rc))
    # subscribe for all devices of user
    mqttc.subscribe('+/devices/+/up')

# gives message from device
def on_message(mqttc, obj, msg):
    try:
        x = json.loads(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
        # metadata
        app = x["app_id"]
        device = x["dev_id"]
        deveui = x["hardware_serial"]
        port = x["port"]
        confirmed = x["confirmed"]
        counter = x["counter"]
        payload_fields = x["payload_raw"]
        datetime = x["metadata"]["time"]
        gateways = x["metadata"]["gateways"]
        frequency = x["metadata"]["frequency"]
        modulation = x["metadata"]["modulation"]
        data_rate = x["metadata"]["data_rate"]
        air_time = x["metadata"]["airtime"]
        coding_rate = x["metadata"]["coding_rate"]

        for gw in gateways:
            gateway_id = gw["gtw_id"]
            timestamp = gw["timestamp"]
            time = gw["time"]
            channel = gw["channel"]
            gwrssi = gw["rssi"]
            gwsnr = gw["snr"]

            # decoding the payload_field
        payload_r = (pybase64.b64decode(payload_fields + "="))
        # decoding the Payload_r to Byte-Ascii string
        payload_h = binascii.hexlify(payload_r)
        # Byte to tekst
        node_data = (payload_h.decode("utf-8)"))        #this is the variable i would like to use in devdata()
        # Printing data, + str(payload_fields) + ", "

        print(str(app) + ", " + str(device) + ", " + str(deveui) + ", " + str(port) + ", " + str(counter) + ", "
          + str(node_data) + ", " + str(modulation) + ", " + str(datetime) + ", " + str(frequency) + ", "
          + str(confirmed) + ", " + str(data_rate) + ", " + str(air_time) + ", " + str(coding_rate) + ", "
          + str(gateway_id) + ", " + str(timestamp) + ", " + str(time) + "," + str(channel) + ", "
          + str(gwrssi) + ", " + str(gwsnr))

        return node_data    #return data for use in devdata()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass

def devdata():
    node_data = on_message()            # trying to use this as the Variable
    temperatur = int(node_data[2:4], 16)
    print("temperatur =", temperatur)
`
```

Comment: The entire content of `on_message()` is wrapped in a giant try/except block.  If an exception is caught, the function returns None.  Are you seeing any output that has an error message?

Comment: Hi, there is no error.

Comment: I don't see how that is possible.  The only way that function should be able to return `None` is if an exception is caught, in which case the exception message should also be printed.

Comment: Could you include your entire output when you run this code?

Comment: here is the print-out, only the print inside the the jason.load is in output:

Adeunis_fieldtester, fieldtester_001b20000001873, 0018B20000001873, 1, 22586, 9f1e5545360001138370393e0b0d5d0807, LORA, 2020-05-28T21:31:37.498777155Z, 867.7, True, SF7BW125, 71936000, 4/5, seas-nve004a4926, 3843426084, 2020-05-28T21:31:37Z,0, -35, 7.5

Comment: My guess is that i cannot use the variable "return node_data" from inside the json.load.
should i change into a list?

Comment: Your code is a bit strange. first of all, you shouldn't be able to call `on_message` like the way you did, without those three required positional arguments. Python must throw an exception at this point. after that even if node_data is None, you have to see another exception for `node_data[2:4]` as you are trying to subscript a None type. are you sure you are calling devdata() at all?

Comment: i found that the try/except was encapsulating data, when i removed that everything worked as it should.